# gocql: unable to create session: control: unable to connect to initial hosts: Failed to login

Tags: cassandra, gocql

```
cluster := gocql.NewCluster("1.2.3.4") //replace PublicIP with the IP addresses used by your cluster.
    cluster.Keyspace = "testkeyspace"
    cluster.Port = 9042

    cluster.DisableInitialHostLookup = true
    cluster.Authenticator = gocql.PasswordAuthenticator{Username: "test", Password: "testpwd"}
    cluster.ProtoVersion = 4 //replace the username and password fields with their real settings.
    cluster.Consistency = gocql.Quorum
    cluster.CQLVersion = "3.4.5"
    cluster.IgnorePeerAddr = true
    cluster.DefaultIdempotence = true
    cluster.Timeout = time.Second * 30
    cluster.ConnectTimeout = time.Second * 30
    session, err := cluster.CreateSession()
    //  session, err := ccfg.CreateSession()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error in session", err)
        return
    }
    defer session.Close()
```

i am trying to connect and running into issues. i was able to connect with cqlsh on my local and gocql driver fails with this error message i have go1.14 and cassandra version as
`cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 4.0.0.608 | CQL spec 3.4.5 | Native protocol v66`

thanks
Chakri

Comment: The error message sounds like your authentication credentials are wrong. Does `cqlsh 1.2.3.4 -u test -p testpwd` work?

Comment: yep cqlsh works with  the above credentials. above output is from cqlsh show version command   cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 4.0.0.608 | CQL spec 3.4.5 | Native protocol v66

Answer (score 0):

The error you posted indicates that either the username or password (or both) is incorrect. You need to verify that you have put in the correct credentials in your app. Cheers!

Comment: yes i have tried with cqlsh with above credentials and they seem to work